# Need magento 1.9.3.3 to apply patch

Tags: security, patches, magento-1.9.3.3, security-scan-tool

I want to know list of patches for my website which is in 1.9.3.3 version of magento please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Its very easy to find the security patches that your website needs.Visit this [link](https://magento.com/security) and click go to security scan.There you will have to enter your domain name and it will scan the site for you.It will help you find the security patches required and also improvements needed for the website.
You can also try it with https://www.magereport.com/scan/?s=https://drugabusecontrol.com/

Comment: ok this is helpfull

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to upgrade to the latest 1.9.4.2 which includes all security patches.

For Magento 1.9.3.3 you need the following patches.

- SUPEE-11155
- SUPEE-11086
- SUPEE-10975
- SUPEE-10888
- SUPEE-10752
- SUPEE-10570
- SUPEE-10415
- SUPEE-10266
- SUPEE-9767 V2

See also this list by JH:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTbU9Bq130zrrsJwLIB9d8qnGfYZnkm4jBlfNaBF19M/edit#gid=192164130

Comment: thanks very much. will try out and will let you know.